# WMQ Exception CWSMQ0006E ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode 2, Reason 2102 while creating connection

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am facing some issue in WMQ when trying to establish connection with WMQ Topic from out C# application.

```
IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2102.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.
See the linked exception for more information.
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String userID, String password)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection()**
```

WMQ Client Log:

```
AMQ12984.0.FDC 2018/03/08 06:26:22.700000 Installation1 w3wp 12984 4235 XC035007 xcsCreateThread   xecP_E_NO_RESOURCE       OK
AMQ12984.0.FDC 2018/03/08 06:26:23.403000 Installation1 w3wp 12984 4235 XC022001 xcsDisplayMessage rrcE_CREATE_THREAD_ERROR OK**
```

The connectivity works perfectly fine the whole day but sometime in morning it starts throwing the exception. We are reusing the Factory object across difference services but each time service Open - Write Message - Close the connection in factory.

We are using IBM Client V7.5.0.5. This exception is occurring on multiple servers, but on different times, so can't blame processor or server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> We are reusing the Factory object across difference services but each
>   time service Open - Write Message - Close the connection in factory.

Are you actually closing the connection?  Or you letting the framework close the connection which of course it is not?  Check your code and explicitly close the connection in your code.

Comment: We are not closing connection to the factory (IConnectionFactory) and reusing the factory object for all the threads. However, after writing the message to the Topic, we Stop / Close / Dispose objects related to connectionFactory.CreateConnection, connectionFactory.CreateDestination and connection.CreateSession.